# Using reveal pattern to make ES6 class properties private

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I want to make `Xl` class (an ES6 class) properties private, thus prevent direct manipulation of the properties. I choose to use revealing module pattern as follows,

**index.js**

```
import Xl from './xiuli';

function Xiuli(selector) {
  const xiuli = new Xl(selector);
  return {
    goto: xiuli.goto.bind(xiuli),
    pre: xiuli.pre.bind(xiuli),
    next: xiuli.next.bind(xiuli),
    onTransitionend: xiuli.onTransitionend.bind(xiuli),
  };
}
module.exports = Xiuli;
```

Do I violate any best practices or do something bad in here? Especially in `xiuli.<method>.bind(xiuli)`

Does using `WeakMap` in `Xl` class better than this approach? (Given that my library is targeting IE 11+)

I'm familiar with the approach of using getters / setters in the class constructor. But I do not prefer that approach since it creates new functions instance with each new object.

Comment: How is this related to ES6 classes? Just curious.

Comment: I mean, I see no trace of using ES6 features here at all. Even the module syntax is not it

Comment: @oniondomes I just wanted to specify `Xl` is an ES6 class since I does not provide the source of the Xl class. I could have use `export function Xiuli(selector){..}`, just my eslint throwing a `Prefer default export. (import/prefer-default-export)` warning. Why I added the es6-class tag is because I wanted to hide the properties of an ES6 class.

Comment: I don't think a function becomes a ES6 class just because one says it is. You probably should have listened to your linter and replaced it with `export default....`; mixing module styles is far away from being a good idea from my perspective. As for your actual question, it's kinda hard to tell what exactly your goal is, thus what would be better to do in your case. In the example code you provide I don't see why you need `Xl` function at all.

Comment: My goal is not converting a function into a ES6 class. My goal is to return an object with some selective methods, thus restricts the direct manipulation of the underline instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I violate any best practices or do something bad in here?

It does no longer matter how `X1` is implemented since the users of your library don't see it any more. It's not possible to take advantage of it being an ES6 `class` any more, such as being able to inherit from it. The exported `Xiuli` is just a factory function returning object literals, which means not even `instanceof` will work any more.

> I'm familiar with the approach of using getters / setters in the class constructor. But I do not prefer that approach since it creates new functions instance with each new object.

Well, `bind` does create new functions as well, it's not better at all, and there's also the additional object literal that acts as a wrapper around the actual instance. Whether this needs more memory than constructor-scoped getters depends on the number of private "properties" vs the number of public methods. The factory function doesn't look much easier to use though, and using getters is probably more DRY.

Comment: number of  private "properties" >  number of public methods. How about using `WeakMap`?

Comment: You can always do that, it's probably much more memory-friendly than creating any instance-specific function objects. (I just personally don't like WeakMap syntax)